# startx doesn't do anything

Tags: startup

I SSH into a fresh install of a Ubuntu Server and installed the Ubuntu Desktop using the steps [here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-a-gui-on-ubuntu) with gdm3.

But then when I reboot, it just brings me back to the terminal and then when I do startx, it just does nothing and remains idle. [image]

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Are you trying to see the desktop through SSH?  SSH is not designed to show you the desktop itself.  You could try `ssh -X` or  `ssh -Y` but I don't think that will work either for viewing the desktop.  You would need some sort of VNC or RDP connection to the host.

Comment: thanksI enabled xrdp on the terminal and then RDPed into it. But once I enter the username and password, it logs me in and then closes the window. should anything else be enabled as well?